# Get Device Memory Xcode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory, darwin

I really need to know of a way to get the current device’s:

1. Active Memory
2. Inactive Memory
3. Wired Memory
4. Free Memory
5. Total Memory

Any information, code or anything is helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desktop uses the Mach call `host_statistics64()` to get that information. You can see it in use in the [source code for the vm_stat command](http://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-498.2/vm_stat.tproj/vm_stat.c).